Promoting the site
Our site is very low on visits per day. Only 98 visits per day at the moment. We must do something!
If you're reading this now, please consider adopting any of these measures to help us grow the site! Why? Because if the sites grows, we'll become a fully launched site. If not, the site will be closed. That's right. So help us (helping you too) and propose new ideas!
So far we thought you could:

Share the site on your SE profile, across all the sites you're on. If you share the link as a referrer, you'll get more reputation on Area51.

Share questions with the buttons! Here are the buttons to share a question:


Share the site on your social network account, on forums, penpals sites, in your local university, with friends!


Got another idea that is not here? Share it and post an answer now! :)
But... How do we know the site's health? First of all, check this post by Robert Cartaino where he says:

Of the statistics you cited, the only two that are part of the minimum requirements for graduation are as follows:

90+ days in beta
10+ editors (users with 2000+ reputation)
5+ closers (users with 3000+ reputation)

The rest of the statistics we look at, but they are primarily for the communities to know how they're doing.

And since he links to two blog posts, give a look to them:

Does this site have a chance of succeeding?
When Will My Site Graduate?


Do you think it would be helpful to talk to the Japanese SE moderators? They get 472 visitors/day!

@gonnastop I could try to talk to them. Do you mean like a Twin-Partnership Program? :P

I was thinking that we could ask how and where they promoted their site. How is the number of visitors per day calculated?

@gonnastop I think it simply counts how many unique IP's connect to the site each day. The reason why I think they are having success is that Japanese is very popular. I thought Chinese was as popular but well...

Maybe we are not getting enough questions? I think that's what keeps me from coming back to check the site everyday.

I think a good place to start is looking for a way to promote out site is by asking the users we currently have what they think.
We should find out out what attracted current users to the site. If we can better gauge the current user base that we already have, we can see what we currently have and go from there.

What is your profession? 
How did you managed to find the SE?
What got you into Chinese? Where do you want to go with it?
What did they expect or hope to get out of the site they first
discovered or heard about it?
What do they think about the current state and where do they wish to
take it?
Are there any good websites/communities (doesn't have to be Chinese-related, both on and off SE) that we can look to as an example?

I agree with @Alenanno that the one of the primary issue we are having is that Chinese is not as popular as other language (at least in North America, even though, it second-most-common language on the Internet).
I think we should look at how to make the Chinese language more appealing and more specifically define how we engage our target audience.
Maybe we can work with other established communities or institutions that promote the Chinese language like the Chinese Language and Culture Initiative, where we can get guest speakers for a short Q and A session, in chat and in exchange help them promote bring teachers from China to teach in U.S. schools, or helping to educate academical representatives about China and it's culture. 
This way we can also help educators develop a better curriculum for teaching/promoting Chinese and just be just a Q&A site.
